# Laravel: Can't display array value in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I store json in my db and retrive it in decoded format using my model.
I pass the value to a blade and tries to display a value from json there.

I `dd($properties)` and gets this:

```
array:1 [
  "like" => 10
]
```

This works: `{{dd($properties["like"])}}` gets correct integer value `10`

But when I do `{{$properties["like"]}}` it returns `"Cannot access offset of type string on string"`.

But `$properties` is not a string, coz when I `{{$properties}}`, it gives `"htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given"` . `{{gettype($properties)}}` gives `array`.

Comment: I don't have experience with this issue but maybe it's an `ArrayObject` , try to access it via object notation `$properties->like`, or try `$properties{"like"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for loop

```
foreach($properties as $property) {
     $property["like"];
}
```